# How to gracefully shutdown spring-kafka consumer application

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

i have implemented `spring-kafka` consumer application.

i wants consumer application graceful shutdown.

the current consumer application is terminated with the Linux command `kill -9 pid`

i am using `@KafkaListener` annotation now.

if i quit the Spring boot app, i want to reliably close the consumer, what should i do ?

---

i've been using `@Predestory` to reliably exit the spring boot app, but i'm not quite sure if this has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`kill -9` is like the death star

```
     Some of the more commonly used signals:

     1       HUP (hang up)
     2       INT (interrupt)
     3       QUIT (quit)
     6       ABRT (abort)
     9       KILL (non-catchable, non-ignorable kill)
     14      ALRM (alarm clock)
     15      TERM (software termination signal)
```

The default kill signal SIGTERM (15)

`kill <pid>`

Boot will shut down everything gracefully; it registers a shutdown hook, which can't intercept a `kill -9`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stop a single consumer, just call `stop()` on the listener container.

---

Note that when you call `stop()` the container will process all records that have been fetched from `poll()` until that point, before the container shuts down.

Comment: Since version 2.5.11, there is a new container property `stopImmediate`; when true, the container will stop after processing the current record.

Comment: @GaryRussell do we have something similar for reactive kafka? I was checking in "KafkaReceiver".. could not find any.

Comment: No; once the records are emitted to the pipeline they are no longer accessible by the  receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will put here my thoughts on this.
Either `kill` will cause thread interruption. It's ok, when the message consumer is single-threaded.
But in case if message processing using threads inside (or executors, anything that works in different threads), those will catch the interruption too. And no way to prevent it.

In the case of batch mode, it is even hard to track propper offset, because some messages have been processed, and some - no. So there is another approach - tell the consumer to stop listening but finish processing or those items that are polled in this step.
So we should not use any of the interruptions, but the stopping should be a programmatic command to the application.

Comment: There is a way to prevent async threads to be inrrupted uppon default kill: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ExecutorConfigurationSupport.html#setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown-boolean-

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides a sub-project Actuator, which allows you to receive information about the status of a component as well as control it.

In order to install it, simply add two dependencies to pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Also in the properties file you must assign the port number :

```
server.port= your free port like 8081
```

Also, in order for the actuator to switch the component off correctly, another parameter must be set in the properties file :

```
server.shutdown=graceful
```

To turn a component off using an actuator, use the command :

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/actuator/shutdown' -i -X POST
```

[All Actuator's commands](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#overview)